# helm restrict override certain fields during helm upgrade

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to build a chart and define parameters with default values. While doing helm install, the user can override certain fields using user defined values.yaml. But I don't want the user to change the certain fields during upgrade.

For Ex:

```
values.yaml
    id: "testId"
    name: "testName"
```

It should throw error when user tries to change the value during helm upgrade.

```
values.yaml
    id: "idChanged"
    name: "testName"
```

Is there a way to do it in helm charts?

Answer (score 0):

You can use values.schema.json file as a reference schema with all the properties to handle this scenario. further info you can read from [here](https://www.arthurkoziel.com/validate-helm-chart-values-with-json-schemas/)

During helm upgrade if certain values have to to be skipped, set the readonly option to true and this would result in error if user tried to update them during helm upgrade

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have values.schema.json where i define the type of parameter. Is there something that i can do apart from these? Can i set the parameter to be read only during upgrade ? considering the "id" field getting changed is user typo error. how can we prevent this internally without set option ?